# Routed traffic with cookies Nginx

Tags: node.js, cookies, nginx

first time i'm trying to setup nginx.
I have following problem i would like to solve.

I have two versions of backend v1 and v2.

User is routed to "/v2" (proxy_pass '127.0.0.1:3000;')

Traffic tru "/" (javascript + sockets) has be routed to the same server '127.0.0.1:3000;' by looking at the cookie.

Heres my problem the cookie doesn't exists and therefore 404 will be returned

Any suggestion?

```
map $cookie_version $site_version {
    default     "";
    "v1"  "version=v1;Domain=localhost;Path=/";
    "v2"  "version=v2;Domain=localhost;Path=/";
}

server {    
  listen 8081;
  server_name localhost;

location / {
    if ($cookie_version ~* "v1") {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }       
    if ($cookie_version ~* "v2") {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }   
}

location /v1 {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    set $cookie_version "v1";
    add_header Set-Cookie $site_version;

    rewrite ^/v1(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location /v2 {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    set $cookie_version "v2";
    add_header Set-Cookie $site_version;

    rewrite ^/v2(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, read why if is evil http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil. Use `map` instead.
My suggestion:

```
map $cookie_version $mybackend {
  default "127.0.0.1:3000";
  "v1" "127.0.0.1:8080";
  "v2" "127.0.0.1:3000";
}
...
location / {
  proxy_pass http://$mybackend;
}
...
location ~ ^/(?<cver>v[12])/ {
  ...
  add_header Set-Cookie "version=$cver;Domain=localhost;Path=/";
  rewrite ^/v[12]/(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: ah, thanks... But i doesnt save the cookie for some reason i dont understand. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you receive this cookie form server? Check with dev tools of browser. Probably you trouble because localhost domain, try something like localhost.com (edit your `hosts` file for it)